# How to debug internal testing app on play store

Tags: android, google-play-console

I recently published an app on play store, but it has some error that is crashing the app on start up, every thing is working fine on android emulator. I have tested both release and debug build on emulator and it works fine, but when i publish on internal testing, and download from their, app crashes. Is it possible to proper debug internal testing app published on play console?